# Django initialization stuck at import netrc

Tags: django, python-requests

My django app starts very slowly. I ran `python -v manage.py check` and it stucks at line

```
import 'netrc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7efff40f3d30>
```

I found this related question : [Django "Performing System Checks" is running very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652707/django-performing-system-checks-is-running-very-slow)

Here it says he removed the elastic beanstalk urls from ALLOWED_HOSTS and it fixed. I did that too but my app still stucks at that import statement. What else can cause that?